# How can I write to /dev/kmsg?

Tags: c

I want to write to /dev/kmsg so I can compare user space logging in an application to things that are happening in the kernel.

I wrote a simple application that should log a message similar to how you can do this from the command line with `echo "foo" > /dev/kmsg`

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int fdKmsg = -1;
  fdKmsg = open("/dev/kmsg", O_WRONLY);

  if (fdKmsg != -1)
  {
    dprintf(fdKmsg, "-- Hello World --\n");
    close(fd);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Unable to get file descriptor\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, when I run this even as root, I don't see anything either in dmesg or in /proc/kmsg. What am I missing? Even with a call to fsync(), it doesn't appear to write to dmesg.

Comment: Do you run it as `root` or as `sudo`?

Comment: `/dev/kmsg` seems to be a device special applications _read_ from and very rarely write to. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/568295/391809

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be "written" via `printk` from the kernel side. But looks like in some cases (but for unknown reasons) it can be written from user space: https://serverfault.com/questions/140354/how-to-add-message-that-will-be-read-with-dmesg

Comment: Yep, running as root/sudo. I realize it's "supposed" to be written via printk(). However, we need to interleave user application logging and kernel messages to debug a weird issue. This was the quickest (and dirtiest) way I could think to do it.

Comment: @Maxthecat In one of the comments in the linked question they say it works only as root, but not `sudo`.. UPD, ah, but it does not apply here, as you are not using shell for this

Comment: You don't need `fsync()`, it's not a disk device that's written asynchronously. If you're able to open the device, writing to it should work.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why this isn't working. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/testing/dev-kmsg says that writes to `/dev/kmsg` should work.

Comment: You could always write a very simple module for that. Also seems cleaner to me. Also, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585919/what-is-the-difference-between-proc-kmsg-and-dev-kmsg) - are you sure, you are accessing /dev/kmsg and not /proc/kmsg and that /dev/kmsg is indeed a device node and not a symlink to /proc/kmsg for some reason?

Comment: A module is canonically correct. However, in actuality, I have to hook this up to a user program which means I'd have to expose a /dev, /proc, or socket interface of my own to copy the messages to the kernel and then print them. At that point, I might as well just use /dev/kmsg.

Yep, the program you see is exactly what I'm trying as my toy example. Running as root (id 0) on Ubuntu. I'd love it if someone else could try it and tell me if they have similar or different results. Edit: I should point out, that when I command line echo to /dev/kmsg it works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that dprintf() will not work in this case. However, calling write() will
work. I'm not sure why this is, but I would guess that the printf() functions don't call the write method for the exposed /dev interface.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int fdKmsg = -1;
  fdKmsg = open("/dev/kmsg", O_WRONLY);
  char *buf = "Hello World\n";

  if (fdKmsg != -1)
  {
    //dprintf(fdKmsg, "-- Hello World --\n");
    write(fdKmsg, buf, strlen(buf) + 1);
    close(fd);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Unable to get file descriptor\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```